# get data from the last X minutes sqlite

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I have this query:

```
SELECT who,whenAT
FROM seen
WHERE whenAT <= Datetime('now', '-5 minutes')
```

DateTimes stored in whenAT are formatted like this "10/12/2011 12:33:13 AM" whenAT is a TimeStamp.

that current query returns all records for some reason.

i'm inserting the datetime from code as DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") this is what is being saved into the table "10/12/2011 12:33:13 AM" i want to get all records within the last 5 minutes. everything i have tried either returns all records or no records.

Answer (score 2):

Your query should be

```
SELECT who,whenAT FROM seen WHERE whenAT >= Datetime('now', '-5 minutes')
```

To get the last 5 minute, < will get everything besides the last 5 minutes

Comment: That does not work. just returns nothing at all (yes there are items with a timestamp within the last 5 minutes of running the query)

Comment: alternative would be to manipulate the datetime in code: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5) and pass it to the query

Comment: so are you saying i should just fetch ALL records in code and process them to see if they match my criteria there?

Comment: No im saying instead of your query being "SELECT who,whenAT FROM seen WHERE whenAT <= Datetime('now', '-5 minutes')" make it "SELECT who,whenAT FROM seen WHERE whenAT >= "+ DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5)

Comment: No matter what i try it either returns all of them or nothing. i tried doing "sql = string.Format("SELECT who,whenAT FROM seen WHERE whenAT >= '{0}'", DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5));" returns all records even tho they have a TimeStamp from over 40 minutes ago

Answer (score 1):

as Fatal510 said, you need to add the modifier 'localtime'

here some reference about datetime modifier https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

and here some example

`SELECT who,whenAT FROM seen WHERE whenAT >= Datetime('now', '-5 minutes', 'localtime')`

Answer (score 0):

needed to add the modifier 'localtime'